sympy.init_printing() not working in IPython terminal session
I wanted to do some quick calculations and I was too lazy to open a notebook file, so I just opened an IPython session in the terminal. According to sympy's documentation calling sympy.init_printing() should initialize pretty printing in a python or IPython session. However, when I tried it, I didn't get pretty printing:

I tried running with use_latex="mathjax"/True/False, use_latex=True/False, and I tried using IPython.display.display(). Nothing worked. I always get the raw version of my expressions like in the image above. What am I missing here? How can I enable pretty printing in a terminal session with sympy?

The commands as shown give pretty printing for me with GNOME terminal on Linux. It might be something to do with the terminal that you are using (I don't recognise what terminal that is).

It's PowerShell on Windows 11
